# Overlay an animated div on top of a JavaScript animated canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently found a codepen with some JavaScript which creates a cool looking node effect: http://codepen.io/thetwistedtaste/pen/GgrWLp

as well as this 'glitch' effect on text using @keyframes animation:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyjLJZ

I wanted to implement both on my practice website but I'm finding it hard to place the text on top of the canvas with the animation.

Here is what I have at the moment:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVeVvE

What I want to achieve is the 'TEXT' to be in the centre with the glitch animation as well as the moving nodes in the background.

Is this possible?

I've tried adding a z-index to the wrap class but I don't think I'm using it correctly.

Here's what it looks like:

```
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
```

Do I need to add a z-index to every frame of the animation? Would anyone be able to help me out with this please?

Without using the z-index, the animation works fine but the text appears at the bottom of the page which is where I don't want it to be.

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. It looks like the text is in the center with the glitch animation and the moving nodes in the background already.

Comment: @jBot-42 The glitch animation for 'TEXT' isn't working on my end? That's odd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in the latest versions of Safari and Chrome, however the `clip` property is deprecated and may not work in certain browsers. [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) should be used instead, and it will need vendor prefixes. See [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/pJjVob/) for a demo.

Comment: I've just asked a group of my friends to try it on their fully updated browsers and it doesn't work for them either. As mentioned in the main question, the glitch effect works fine without the z-index